# How to bring micro controller out of sleep mode after a certain amount of ticks on a crystal?

Tags: embedded

I am writing code (C using Nordic SDK) that runs on a NRF51822.  The board also has a 32.768khz crystal on it that I want to use to wake up the chip after a certain amount of time.  How do I go about bringing the board out of sleep mode after an amount of time that can be set by a variable in code?

Comment: what did the chip documentation say about this and what part of that did you not understand?

Comment: It said "A countdown watchdog timer using the low-frequency clock source (LFCLK) offers configurable and robust
protection against application lock-up. The watchdog can be paused during long CPU sleep periods for low
power applications and when the debugger has halted the CPU."  Does this mean that there is a WDT already in the chip that I should be able to configure and access through code?

Comment: I dont see sleep mode in the documentation, what specific mode do you wish to be in.  The documentation describes how to get out of each of the modes.  What mode are you after, what did you try (show a representative example of the code) and what did it do vs what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

This chip is based on an ARM Cortex M0 and assuming you have put the chip into sleep mode using WFI (wait for interrupt), then you will need an interrupt to wake it up. That implies using some peripheral, presumably clocked off of the 32 kHz clock, that can generate an interrupt based on that clock period. The usual choice is a timer.

Comment: Ok.  Will I need a WDT to accomplish this?  Also do I just set the period it needs to wait and the chip will figure out when the clock has ticked enough times?

Comment: Watchdog timers and general purpose timer peripherals tend to serve different roles in a system. I'm not completely versed in the peripherals on this chip and am far too lazy to read the documentation on your behalf just so I can retype it in here. I concur with old_timer. Show us some code containing what you have tried and folks here will be better able to help.